# How to make a file undeletable in hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I have a requirement i.e. I want to make the files which comes into hdfs un-deletable .Is there any option to do this ?.Actually in linux we have a command **chattr** to make file immutable/undeletable so that no one can delete that file till root removes that immutable flag(chattr +i),is there any such kind of facility in hadoop ?.Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that there is any equivalent to chattr. If your main purpose is stopping people from doing this by mistake, change the owner to hdfs (the Hadoop root), and set it so that only root can delete it through file permissions.

However by default, anyone can sign in as root through the command line, as hadoop is not designed for security out of the box. In order to get true security, you will need to enable kerberos authentication for hadoop, which gets rid of the command line access vulnerability.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response @Davis Broda,is there any  approach to do "chattr" operation in hdfs ?

Comment: @prasad As I said in my answer, I do not believe there is a way to do this. However if only the root address has deletion privileges, then it seems like it would work in a fairly similar manner. Given that hdfs is read-many,write-once, there should be no circumstances where someone needs write access except to delete. As such the only difference would be that the file owner (which should be root, or an equivalent) can delete with a simple rm command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the file permissions to protect the file. More details are here:

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html

Comment: thanks for your reply,but  I am not able to get exact solution for my issue from this link